# How to remove text from canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

My problem is that when I am clicking on button, `callfunction()` method called and counter is incremented by 5, when I am again click counter incremented by 5 and displayed 10 on given location my problem is that when counter is incremented previous number is not erased and displayed incremented number on previous number. I want to remove previous number and display next incremented number. I have following code:

```
var count=0;
function callfunction()
   {
         context.fillText(count,200,200);
         count = count+5;
         //context.fillText("",200,200);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fillText` with background colour, if it's monochromatic. Or preserve what was there before as image data, then paste it over later when you want to erase the text.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know is to clear the full canvas element using `canvas.fillRect`.

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5nnZ/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0;
function update(){
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    canvas.fillText(count,200,200);
    //Draw anything else...

}

setInterval("update()",1000/60); //60 Frames per second

button.onclick = function(){ //Change button to your button element
    count += 5;
}
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use clearRect() to just clear a portion of the canvas...

If you know the size of your text field, set clearRect() to a rectangle large enough to clear that text field:

```
var count=0;
function callfunction()
   {
    context.clearRect(200, 190, 50, 10); // clears a text field 50 x 10, above baseline
    context.fillText(count,200,200);
    count = count+5; 
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing the canvas first:

```
    var count=0;
    function callfunction()
   {
         context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 ,canvas.height , canvas.width );
         context.fillText(count,200,200);
         count = count+5;
         //context.fillText("",200,200);
   }
```