# How to remove text over an image from Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

After searching for placing text over an image in Canvas I found this snippet

```
jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pQYz9/ (found it on stackoverflow, I lost the question)
```

This snippet places any amount of text over an image. Is it possible to show a cross over each textbox? so that I can remove the selected text by pressing it. The closet answer I found is on this post. But this post talks about clearing the whole canvas and redrawing everything except for the item that you want to remove.

[how to remove text from canvas in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631002/how-to-remove-text-from-canvas-in-javascript)

My end goal is to have have an app where you can upload an image as a background, place some text on it anywhere you want and then save that canvas as an image.

Comment: Is this the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547611/how-to-insert-an-image-in-canvas-and-after-that-insert-text-in-this-canvas , you lost?

Comment: Here's the question you *lost*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547611/how-to-insert-an-image-in-canvas-and-after-that-insert-text-in-this-canvas